# How long should I wait to see the result of a request to Place Action Link Google My business?

Tags: google-my-business-api, google-my-business

Using [Place Action Link API of Google my Business](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/placeactions/rest/v1/locations.placeActionLinks/create), I have created a `place action link` for booking an appointment for every location I needed. I want to know how long does it take to see the result and am I going to be able to see this link on google results as a direct link to book an appointment? Here is some parts of my Java code:
supposing "myBusinessPlaceActions" is a variable which initialise the API and takes care of credentials as well:

```
            PlaceActionLink link = new PlaceActionLink();
            link.setUri("the specific url");
            link.setPlaceActionType("APPOINTMENT"); 
            myBusinessPlaceActions.locations().placeActionLinks().create("my location name", link).execute();
```